# Pass data to ejs partials using Webpack 2

Tags: javascript, webpack, ejs

I am using Webpack 2 and ejs-template-loader I can get data for my page however I need to pass some section of data to one of partials.

```
<% 
var data = htmlWebpackPlugin.options.data;
var carouselElement = data.carouselElement;
if (data) {  %>
<!-- Header -->
<%- include ../../components/avalon/header/header.ejs %>
    <div class="page-mask">
        <div class="main-content <%= carouselElement%>">
            <%- include ../../components/hero.image/hero.image.ejs %>
            <%- include ../../components/content.carousel/content.carousel.ejs {carouselElement} %>
            <%- include ../../components/experiences/experiences.ejs %>
        </div>
    </div>
<%}%>
```

above code gave me error like this

> ENOENT: no such file or directory

Do you know how to pass data to partials?

Comment: Your path is not correct for sure, did you set the layout in your server side as well ?

Comment: when I use <%- include ../../components/content.carousel/content.carousel.ejs %> it works. I don't know how to pass data to partials

Comment: look at my answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

to pass data in a partial in EJS with `include` :

```
<%- include( '../mypage', { data: "mydata" }); %>
```

To show it in `mypage.ejs`

```
<%= data %> // will show mydata
```

---

with EJS loader, it seems to be like this :

```
var mainPage = require("ejs!./mainPage.ejs");
var subPage = require("ejs!./subPage.ejs");

var renderedPage = _.mainPage('<%= mainPage %>', { title: 'data', subPage:subPage  });

<%= renderedPage %>
```

In `mainPage.ejs`:

```
<main>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <%= subPage({ title:'sub page', content: 'This is the subPage' }) %>
</main>
```

In `subPage.ejs`:

```
<div>
    <h2><%= title %></h2>
    <p><%= content %></p>
</div>
```

Don't forget to add lodash plugin in your webpack conf file :

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        _: "underscore"
    })
]
```

Enjoy !

Comment: Still getting Error. Are you running it using Webpack 2 ejs loader?